# Increment/ Decrement a value in firebase realtime database with in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I want to setup a counter in my firebase realtime database.
In my app trying to use it for counting number of API requests.
Below is the shortest and simplest extraction of the code from my app which works exactly same and produce same error as in my app.

Structure of my firebase realtime database:

`Counter: 1000`

My code(indd.js):

```
require('dotenv').config();

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: "https://awesomeURL.firebaseio.com"
});

const database = admin.database();

const rw = () => {
  const path = "Counter";
  database.ref(path).on("value", snapshot => {
    database.ref(path).set(snapshot.val() - 1);
    console.log(snapshot.val())
  });
}


rw();
```

Content of my **package.json** file

```
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "All my APIs.",
  "main": "indd.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon indd.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12"
  }
}
```

The content of my **.env** file.

The required json file is available in **Project Overview ⚙️ > Service accounts > Generate new private key**

`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = ./adminsdk.json`

**Result**:

Data is successfully decremented in the firebase realtime database and the application crashes producing following error.
[Pastebin Link Of Error Message On Console](https://pastebin.com/T5ugsfF1)

Comment: What is the error? Include it in the post

Comment: It's very long error, so I included a pastebin link at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

You're attaching a permanent listener to the `Counter` by calling `on`. So you code will be called once with the initial value of the counter, and then every time the counter is changed.

And since your callback code changed the counter, that will cause the callback to be called again... and again... and again, until you get the error you got.

To increment the value, you should only get the current value, and not listen for updates, which you can do by using `once()` instead of `on()`:

```
const rw = () => {
  const path = "Counter";
  //                   
  database.ref(path).once("value", snapshot => {
    database.ref(path).set(snapshot.val() - 1);
    console.log(snapshot.val())
  });
}
rw();
```

---

But incrementing the existing value can nowadays be done even easier (and more securely) by using the [atomic server-side increment operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments):

```
const rw = () => {
  const path = "Counter";
  //                                                    
  database.ref(path).set(firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1));
}
rw();
```

Comment: Link to the documentation is referring to Firebase Web SDK. For Node.js, here's the link to [firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.ServerValue#increment)

Answer (score 0):

```
database.ref(path).on("value", snapshot => {
    database.ref(path).set(snapshot.val() - 1);
    console.log(snapshot.val())
  });
```

So here `on` method fire as soon as you update the value, which again update the value, So this is creating a loop

**`update value -> on method fired -> update value -> on method fired ->.....  infinite.`**

Instead of using `on` method, read value once using get or similar method then update your value

**Note :- A better way would be using transaction**